# Custom Drag Sort Listview with Radiobutton

Tags: android, android-listview, radio-button

I have a DSLV with custom adapter which has two textviews and a radiobutton. I want the radiobutton of a particular row to be setchecked(true) when that row is clicked. To do that I used the below mentioned code.

```
    public OnItemClickListener listclk = new OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,long arg3) {


          if(!rad.isChecked())
          {
              rad.setChecked(true);
          }else{
              rad.setChecked(false);

               }
  }
};
```

But its not working properly. Please Help!!...Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

finally the problem got sorted out by adding ..

```
@Override
        public int getViewTypeCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return namelist.size();
        }



        @Override
        public int getItemViewType(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return position;
        }
```

after the getview().

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
(assuming your DSLV is called "list")

```
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
```

Comment: Thanks.. but i have already put 'list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);' in my onCreate. Still not working. The problem is when i click on the first row, the last row radiobutton gets selected and viceversa.

Comment: Have you performed any drag and drops?